# Standing to pull my into a tight hug

Tags: grammar

Could someone explain why the possessive 'my' appears between two prepositions in this reporting clause below

> "Hey college girl," He smiles a bright, perfectly lined smile while
> standing *to* **my** *into* a tight hug.

This excerpt I took from Wattpad, the title of the story is 'After'. Even after re-reading this sentence a few times, it still doesn't make sense to me. Or is it possibly that the author mistakenly miswrote **me**? Even so, I still can't understand. Is it an ellipsis?

Comment: That sentence is mangled. The author probably meant to say "He smiles a bright, perfectly-lined smile while pulling me into a tight hug." I don't know what **perfectly-lined** means, though. You may want to find something better to read...

Comment: I’m closing this question because it asks why a sentence is grammatical, when the sentence is not grammatical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The text on 'Wattpad' is actually:

> "Hey college girl,' He smiles a bright, perfectly lined smile while
> standing to **pull my** into a tight hug.

You missed out 'pull'.

1. 'My' is an obvious typing error for 'me'. he stood to pull her into a hug.
2. Wattpad is a web site where amateur writers may upload their efforts. This one (described as 'fanfiction') shows a number of amateur features - poor punctuation, sentence structure, etc. Not all the stories will be by good writers, and many may be by not-native or unskilled people.